# web browser submit button not invoking second time c#

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control, desktop-application

Am trying to submit a webform pragmatically on button1 click. In first attemp ie after launching my webbrowser from visual studio it automatically submit the form but again clicking on button1, webpage loads but submit button is not invoked. While debugging its shows that the line of code executed but no action takes place.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("xxxx");
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
        }
        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.Url.OriginalString.ToString() == "xxxx")
            {
                if(webBrowser1.ReadyState==WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    HtmlElementCollection doc = webBrowser1.Document.All;
                    foreach (HtmlElement ele in doc)
                    {
                        if (ele.GetAttribute("name").ToString()== "username")
                        {
                            ele.SetAttribute("value","xxxx");
                        }
                        if (ele.GetAttribute("name").ToString() == "password")
                        {
                            ele.SetAttribute("value", "xxxx");
                        }
                        if (ele.GetAttribute("classname") == "btn")
                        {
                            ele.InvokeMember("click");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to setup the `DocumentCompleted` event for the web browser once. In your code you keep adding to the event chain each time the button is pressed which is not the behaviour you want.

You want something like (pseudo code as haven't got VS with me):

```
// When the form/parent loads bind the event ONCE here.
public void FormLoads()
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
}

// Just navigate here and the event will still be raised
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("xxxx");   
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Tried the above method but not worked.Same problem. On first button1 click form is submitted but not on further clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Its Due to your webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted Event is not working when your click on Button.
Just Create one method 
`Private Void Submit();`  and here put your code which you want to perform on click event and call this method from two location one is at button1_click and another webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted so that your code is run at both events.

Comment: webBrowser1_DocumentComplted event is working. while debugging the code breakpoint is active at the line of code, which is in document completed block.

Comment: when you click second time on Button at that time debug it and see it that code from webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted is visit or not.?

Comment: yes, all three things are visited by debugger again ie:if (ele.GetAttribute("name").ToString()== "username")
                        {
                            ele.SetAttribute("value","xxxx");
                        }
                        if (ele.GetAttribute("name").ToString() == "password")
                        {
                            ele.SetAttribute("value", "xxxx");
                        }
                        if (ele.GetAttribute("classname") == "btn")
                        {
                            ele.InvokeMember("click");
                        }

Comment: try `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));` this after `textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentText;` because I think change are done but not reflect in UI. you need to include reference `System.Windows.Threading.dll` .